# Use rx java to load reference data but blocking if necessary

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am trying to implement a solution for storing reference data in the database of my app.

The data is initially stored as JSON files, which I will need to sync from a server on each launch. I have a local copy of the files baked into the app. Each launch I have to check shared preferences for a version. And if it not present, I assume it is the first launch. So i need to read in the files, write the files to the database and fire on completed when that is done. The first screen expects this data to be in the database, so I will be not showing the UI for that screen in this scenario, until the process completes.

However in the future the network call to sync these files can happen asynchronously so want to be able to fire on completed on my observable as soon as i see the shared prefs have a version number and then ill kick of the update completely asynchronously

How can i set up a stream to represent this. I think the stream type will probably be void and i will just fire onCompleted/error as the subscriber doesnt care about the data, only what the process is complete

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
updateChecker.hasUpdates()
       .flatMap(hasUpdates -> {
            if (hasUpdates) {
                return dataUpdater.update();
            }

            return Observable.just(false);
        })
```

Assuming that

```
class UpdateChecker {
    public Observable<Boolean> hasUpdates() {
         return Observable.just(true); // Replace by API call
    }
}

class DataUpdater {
    public Observable<Boolean> update() {
         // update the database here
         return Observable.just(true);
    }
}
```